How to calculate exchange rate (non-PPP rate) if we know purchasing power of two currencies?
Let we know:

old purchasing power in country A (currency A)
old purchasing power in country B (currency B)
old random exchange rate (A/B) (non-PPP rate)

and

new purchasing power in country A (currency A)
new purchasing power in country B (currency B)

How to calculate new exchange rate (A/B)? (non-PPP rate)
Thanks.
